# Why do i have to do the "<-"? Can't i design my function to bypass that?

Tags: r

One of the things i don't like in r is the save process.  Since i am always developing, i have large working environments, and when i save i like to save a **specific object** frequently.  And one of the most annoying things to me is the save process can be so complicated. The object (which is one of up to 10 at a time) is a list of 10 to 20 various data frames (ranging from rasterized images, to medium and large data frames), that are all used in different ways by different functions, which can get very complex.

One of the things that i have not been able to figure out is during my function (if i am performing something that will change that data), i would like to save the changed object back to the directory automatically.  Instead of  i have to do something as follows.  Note this is fine to do with a list of objects through a for loop, but i would like to do it for the object I input into the function.

```
# obtain the name of the object you will be inputing into
# the function in character form
dat.name<-ls(pattern="dat")
#or select it from a list if there are multiple
dat.name<-select.list(ls(pattern="dat"))

# do the function with the object assign it to a new name just in case
# something doesn't work 
tmp.dat<-cell.creator(dat)

#next assign the tmp to the real
assign(dat, tmp.dat)

##or## just do the straight up rename if you are brave, 
#and i am starting to get pretty brave with some of my functions
dat<-cell.creator(dat)

#paste .rdata on the back to create a file name
file.name<-paste(dat.name, ".rdata")

#then... FINALLY save it
save(dat, file=file.name)
```

What i really want to do is internalize those commands into the function, but (unless i am not understanding this) there is nothing that stores the way my object is named during the input, unless i input it with quotations.  Which doesn't allow me to use the tabbing autocomplete in rgui. :(

so, lets say dat is
   bob<-sample(seq(1,1000))

and my function sorts my object

```
bob.sorter<-function(dat){

    dat<-sort(dat)

    return(dat)}
```

So now when i input bob, i would like something to just go ahead and save bob
for me basically do the equivalent of

```
dat<-cell.creator(dat)
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: (a) for a scientist, reproducibility doesn't seem to be paramount; (b) that code doesn't actually sort the vector; (c) if you want to modify object in-place, use C/C++. You can create equally as incomprehensible (at a future date) side effects with `assign()` in R but nobody sane does that.  You can remove the "tedium" with IDE/editor snippets/mapped shortcuts.

Comment: What do you mean reproducibility doesn't seem paramount?  If i am doing a statistical analysis, i am going to work off a script. if i am cleaning data, and prepping binary data frames, and/or working in a learning environment, i can't make a 10000 line script every time i want to do analysis.
I dont think you understand the amount of data i am trying to work with....

Comment: I work with a great deal of very diverse data every single day (I study the internet from dozens of daily whole-internet scans and a network of 200 honeypots). Hackish scripts are a great way to end up with super bad analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but this seems to address part of it. The following is a function which will take an object assigned to a variable (e.g. `bob`) and automatically saves it to a file whose name is the variable name followed by `.rdata` (e.g. `"bob.rdata"`) without the need to actually type the file name:

```
qsave <- function(dat){
  dat.name <- deparse(substitute(dat))
  file.name <- paste0(dat.name,".rdata")
  save(list = dat.name, file=file.name)
}
```

To test it:

```
> bob <- islands
> qsave(bob)
> rm(bob) #bob is now gone
> load("~/bob.rdata") #you can check that this restores bob
```

Comment: Ahh interesting.  What exactly does depares do?

Comment: Use `?deparse` and `?substitute` in the console to get details. The most relevant part (of the help for `substitute`) says "The typical use of substitute is to create informative labels for data sets and plots. The myplot example below shows a simple use of this facility. It uses the functions deparse and substitute to create labels for a plot which are character string versions of the actual arguments to the function myplot."

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this:

```
set.seed(1492) # reproducible science

bob <- sample(1:1000, 500) # the actual way sample() shld be called

str(bob)
##  int [1:500] 278 216 185 111 52 9 848 507 388 763 ...
bob_sorter <- function(dat) {
  dat <- dat[order(dat)] # actual sorting happening 
  dat
}

str(bob_sorter(bob))
##  int [1:500] 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 17 ...

bobs_silly_sorter <- function(dat) {
  passed_in_name <- as.character(substitute(dat)) # pls never do this
  dat <- dat[order(dat)]
  assign(passed_in_name, dat, envir=.GlobalEnv)   # pls never do this
}

str(bob)
##  int [1:500] 278 216 185 111 52 9 848 507 388 763 ...

bobs_silly_sorter(bob)

str(bob)
##  int [1:500] 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 17 ...
```

It's horribad. Your future self will prbly hate you for doing it. And, anyone else who has to work with your code will also end up muttering obscenities under their breath at you every time you walk by them.

Comment: What am i missing here? Do i not understand a fundamental part of programming? What is set.seed?  Why is what you did so horrible?  I understand the importance of scripts and reproducible results.  But what is the difference between this and just following up on my function to see what i've done?

Comment: I'm really just trying to understand where i am going wrong.